# Angular JS Controller Not Responding

Tags: javascript, angularjs

For some reason the controller on chatController.js is not working, since when i told it specifically to alert when it is in the Chat but it didnt. Here is the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/ycpJmsIKJaKlcpoUma43?p=preview

And Cloud9: https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/chattapp

Here is the chatController.js file:

```
app.controller('chatController', ["$scope", function($scope) {
   alert("Works???");
}
]);
```

Comment: `regController` controller is not defined..

Comment: regController?? Yes it is look at my cloud9..

Comment: @GREE Look at your console, thats the error which is reported.

Comment: Nvm @PankajParkar i added the regController now lol

Comment: It was on my cloud9 @Curt i forgot to copy it to my plunker. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On plunker you have got two file with 'chatController' (chatController.js and userSettingController.js) you must change name one of them because if you have got two controller with this same name then one will override the second one.

Comment: Thier not the same name....... userSettingController and chatController is diffrent

Answer (score 1):

**chatController** is defined twice. First in Controllers/chatController.js and then in Controllers/userSettingsController.js

both are linked in index.html

```
<script src = "Controllers/chatController.js"></script>
<script src = "Controllers/userSettingsController.js"></script>
```

Comment: I see a `userSettingsController` in userSettingsController.js, not a `chatController`.

Comment: Controllers are recognized by name. You have 2 controllers defined with this same name and first is redefined by second one. Go to userSettingsController and change it's name from chatController to something else.

Answer (score 1):

You have chatController already defined in userSettingsContoller.js

Answer (score -1):

try `app.controller('chatController', function($scope) {
   alert("Works???");
});`

Comment: This is just a similar version of the same script, which won't work when minified.

Comment: @Curt I thought GREE had problems injecting the scope.. GREE it has nothing to do with the controller then..